# 'Yarn Prisma Migrate Dev' fails with Error: P1000 stating the credentials provided are not valid. These credentials work on all other machines

Tags: postgresql, docker, terminal, yarnpkg, prisma

Whenever I run the command `yarn prisma migrate dev --preview-feature` or just `yarn prisma migrate dev` I receive:

```
Error: P1000: Authentication failed against database server at `localhost`, the provided database credentials for `dbusername` are not valid.
```

The exact same setup and credentials on all other machines work so I know it doesn't have to do with the credentials. This is using a PostgreSQL database on Docker, with the prisma seed and schema in VS Code.

It possibly that the credentials are not actually being checked since I don't see any failed attempts show up in the log on the Docker side of things. Any ideas on how to resolve this or that I need to provide more info?

Comment: I would suggest checking if you have exposed the correct port when your run your database from Docker and it can be connected via `localhost` from your host system.

Comment: Hey @Ryan , is there a way for me to check if this port can be connected via localhost? Sorry I'm not sure how to do that.
Also, I'm not sure if this makes a difference but my postman can make edits to this db in docker.